# multivariable limit question $F(x,y) =(x^{3} + y^{3})/(x^{2} + y^{2})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$F(x,y) =\frac{x^{3} + y^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

Does limit exist at origin?

Comment: What is the denominator? $x^2+y^2$ or $x^2$?

Comment: x^2 + y^2 denominator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider polar coordinate and $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta,r\to 0$.

Comment: check out other answer . why this contradiction

Comment: @SophieClad I don't know why. The limit should be $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$F(x,y) =\frac{x^{3} + y^{3}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$.

$$
0\leq|F(x,y)|\leq \left| x\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}+y \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq|x|+|y|,
$$
hence the limit is equal to 0.

Comment: When changing to polars limits exists and is equl to 0

Comment: @SophieClad Oh! Indeed: domain is too small.

Comment: Bu isnt that one contradiction is enough to screw whole thing up

Comment: The term $y^2$ is approx. $c^{2/3}x^{4/3}$ and cannot be neglected compared to $x^2$.

Comment: @SophieClad I'm sorry for inconvenience. Now the answer is fully corrected (rewritten).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and the limit of $F$ at $(0,0)$ is zero, since, for every $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$, $$|F(x,y)|=\frac{|x^3+y^3|}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\frac{|x|\cdot x^2+|y|\cdot y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant|x|+|y|.$$

Answer (score 0):

$ ( x+y ) ( x^2 + y^2 ) = ( x^3 +y^3) + x y \,( x+y ) $

Now divide by $( x^2 + y^2 )$ and approach x and y from positive side, limit is zero.